# What is the term 't' in Ray definition? Ray Tracing

Tags: raytracing

If the definition of a Ray is given by `Ray = origin + t(direction)` then what is the term `t` suppose to represent? Can't find any tutorials that describe this clearly. Stab at the dark I think it's probably distance but as I understand, if this was to be used in ray tracing does this mean `t` is effectively the distance between the origin of the ray and the plane that I'm checking whether it intersects with?

Comment: `t` is for *time*. If `direction` is a unit vector then `t` is distance, but more generally it is the amount of `direction` travelled along the ray.

Answer (score 2):

That equation is the parametric equation for a straight line. I.e. a line can be described by a point that lies on the line and a vector that points in the same direction as the line.

Conceptually speaking, by plugging into the equation every possible value for *t* parameter from -oo to +oo you get a set of points which comprises the line in its entirety. Given such a description of a line, you can specify any point on the line with a single value of t - the value that, when plugged into the equation, gives you that point.

The parameter itself is meaningless. In the context of a ray-tracing it could be interpreted as time, however unless your renderer is actually attempting to model the propagation of light over time, this is not a useful distinction.

Comment: So in the concept of ray tracing, if I re-arrange the equation to make `t` the subject and use the point on my plane as `P`, if `t > 0` then the point intersects the line?

Comment: The intersection point would only be for a single value of t (unless the line lay on the plane). A plane is parametrically described as a point on the plane and the normal to the plane. More details on solving the intersection here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that direction is normalized then yes, t means distance from the origin. In the definition t might be anything but greater than 0 (otherwise it is a line). So, if you have an intersection, then there exists t' s.t. a point p = origin + t' * direction belongs to your plane.